# Como agregar un botón de Whatsapp en Flutter con DrawerListTitle

Tags: flutter, whatsapp

compré una app realizada en flutter en codecanyon, pero quiero añadirle un botón de whatsapp al menú, cuando el cliente presione el botón este lo lleve a la app de whatsapp y le permita escribir al whatsapp de mi negocio...

he buscado algunas opciones pero en flutter es la primera vez que intento programar..

Este código que les pongo es el código del archivo que crea el menú, como podrán ver he intentado crear un botón con la url api.whatsapp... pero no hace nada al momento de crear el apk...

Como verán en esta parte hice una const _url y en enlace a whatsapp...

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const _url = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5930000000';
    MediaQueryData mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    var bottomPadding = mediaQueryData.padding.bottom;
    var connectionStatus = Provider.of<ConnectivityStatus>(context);

    var themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeNotifier>(context);
```

más abajo añadí este código:

```
                DrawerListTitle(
                    icon: Icons.phone,
                    text: I18n.current.whatsapp,
                    onTap: () => _url),
```

pero no funciona...

Comment: Sí es la primera vez que intentas programar en Flutter te recomiendo seguir estudiando, lee la documentación oficial y/o compra un curso, de lo contrario puedes optar por contratar los servicios de un programador. En la comunidad de Facebook de Flutter en español podrás encontrar muchos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza el paquete url_launcher 6.0.13

luego que importes el paquete, en la propiedad onTap reemplaza

```
    onTap: () async{
      if (await canLaunch(_url)) {
      await launch(_url, forceSafariVC: false);
    }
}
```

Y con eso debería mandarte a la aplicación.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta fue muy útil!, me abre el enlace para Android 10 para abajo, pero por alguna Razón en android 11 no funciona, que crees que se deba?

Comment: te comento que parece que solo en mi teléfono con android 11 no funciona, no se si será porque es xiaomi :S

Comment: a partir de android 11 se han implementado algunos cambios, intenta agregar esta línea de código en tu androidManifest. '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>' tienes mas información aquí: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility. Si la respuesta te sirvio sobre el enlace hacia la aplicación de whatsapp, marca la respuesta como util.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta mira encontré esta linea de código no se por qué el desarrollador original comentó ese código...

  `  <!-- 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"/>
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>`